# Playing songs with android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm new to fragments and I have built a simple app which can play mp3.
So I have one `FragmentActivity` containing `TabFragments`.
One `TabFragment` is a `ListFragment` which contains a list of songs, and the other one is a Fragment which displays the music player.
I can play music when I open the app, but when I click some song in the List, I have no idea how to open the "Play Music" Fragment and play the song I clicked.
Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int tabIndex = 3;
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.selectTab(actionBar.getTabAt(tabIndex));
```

Where `tabIndex` is the index of your music player tab.

Comment: Thank guy. But your answer is just calling PlayMusic tab. I want to play musing song when I clicked song in the list of ListFragment.